# Asking for help about gate drive circuit of a bidirectional dc-dc converter

Tags: mosfet-driver, gate-driving, ir2101

I have a 40V to 400V 500W bidirectional DC-DC converter as shown the image below.

I have trouble designing the gate drive circuit of the switches at the top of the circuit ( I mean S1 to S4 ) because all four switches are high side switches and I do not know what is the best way to drive them.

Is it possible to drive the four switches mentioned earlier without using a separate isolated source as well as a pulse transformer?

Also, all the switches in this circuit are IRFP4768PbF (TO-247 package).
I have IR2xxx and TC44xx family ICs available for this. If possible, please provide your suggested ways based on these ICs.

[image]

Comment: You're looking for a high side MOSFET driver. They're all over the place. Simple IC that usually only requires a cap and diode for external components.

Comment: You can find many eval boards, for example: https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-01160